# Bizarre copy of UNKNOWN in subroutine entry by perl

Tags: perl

I'm hitting a bug in the perl when run the code using "/home/andrew/bin/chroot32.sh  /home/andrew/arscode.plx"

```
Bizarre copy of UNKNOWN in subroutine entry at /home/andrew/arscode.plx line 94.
```

And I'm not quite sure if this is a perl bug or others  bug. This is the relevant part:

```
sub record {
      (my $ctrl = ars_Login($server, $username,$password,undef,undef,$port )) || die "ars_Login:$ars_errstr";
      if (!$ctrl) {print("Could not connect  ($ars_errstr)\n");exit(1);}
      else
      {
           print "login sucess\n";
      }
      (my $entry_id = ars_CreateEntry($ctrl, 'eventCreate',   # <<<< line 94
        '2','ht',
        '7','0', 
        '8','.', 
        '1000000000',encode("big5",decode("utf8","Test"))

        )
        ) or die "Create: $ars_errstr";
        ars_Logoff($ctrl);
  }
```

What is a "Bizarre copy"? And whose fault is it?

Comment: Bizarre copy is a reference to something that was on the stack but was removed. The stack is not ref-counted, so it's possible to still have a reference after the removal. See [#77706](https://github.com/perl/perl5/issues/10612).

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58554716/edit) and fix the indentation of your code so it's readable.

Comment: you're using XS code and it's not doing the right thing https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Bizarre-copy-of-%s-in-%s

Comment: Re "*And whose fault is it?*", Bad XS code (or, unlikely, a bug in Perl). In this case, it's surely `ars_CreateEntry` (or something it calls)

Comment: @choroba, Re "*Bizarre copy is a reference to something that was on the stack but was removed.*", That might be the meaning of "Bizarre copy of UNKNOWN", but that's not what bizarre copy in general means. For example, if a sub puts an AV on the stack, it will result in "Bizarre copy of ARRAY"